# Python numpy array split index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to execute the following code:

```
def calculate_squared_dist_sliced_data(self, data, output, proc_numb):
        for k in range(1, self.calc_border):
            print("Calculating",k, "of", self.calc_border, "\n", (self.calc_border - k), "to go!")
            kmeans = KMeansClusterer.KMeansClusterer(k, data)
            print("inertia in round", k, ": ", kmeans.calc_custom_params(data, k).inertia_)
            output.put( proc_numb,  (kmeans.calc_custom_params(self.data, k).inertia_))

    def calculate_squared_dist_mp(self):
        length = np.shape(self.data)[0]
        df_array = []
        df_array[0] = self.data[int(length/4), :]
        df_array[1] = self.data[int((length/4)+1):int(length/2), :]
        df_array[2] = self.data[int((length/2)+1):int(3*length/4), :]
        df_array[3] = self.data[int((3*length/4)+1):int(length/4), :]
        output = mp.Queue()
        processes = [mp.Process(target=self.calculate_squared_dist_sliced_data, args=(df_array[x], output, x)) for x in range(4)]
        for p in processes:
            p.start()
        for p in processes:
            p.join()

        results = [output.get() for p in processes]
```

When executing `df_array[0] = self.data[int(length/4), :]`, I get the following error:

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

The variable lentgh has the value 20195 (which is correct). I want to do the method `calculate_squared_dist_sliced_data` by multiprocessing, so I need to split the array `data` that is passed to this class.
Here is an example of how this numpy array looks:

```
 [[ 0.          0.          0.02072968 ..., -0.07872599 -0.10147049 -0.44589   ]
 [ 0.         -0.11091352  0.11208243 ...,  0.08164318 -0.02754813
  -0.44921876]
 [ 0.         -0.10642599  0.0028097  ...,  0.1185457  -0.22482443
  -0.25121125]
 ..., 
 [ 0.          0.          0.         ..., -0.03617197  0.00921685  0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.         ..., -0.08241634 -0.05494423
  -0.10988845]
 [ 0.          0.          0.         ..., -0.03010139 -0.0925091
  -0.02145017]]
```

Now I want to split this hole array into four equal pieces to give each one to a process. However, when selecting the rows I get the exception mentioned above. Can someone help me?
Maybe for a more theroretical approach of what I want to do:

```
A   B   C   D
1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8
9   5   4   3
1   8   4   3
```

As a result I want to have for example two arrays, each containing two rows:

```
A  B  C  D
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
```

and

```
A   B   C   D
9   5   4   3
1   8   4   3
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left side of the assignment is not allowed as you list has length 0.

Either fix it to:

```
df_array = [None, None, None, None]
```

or use

```
df_array.append(self.data[int(length/4), :])
...
```

instead.

Comment: just noticed that. looking for the error for about two hours. damn, so simple and stupid:D

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that I tried to use a list like an array...